# Передать динамическое имя таблицы

Tags: java

Всем привет. При создании таблицы БД не могу передать имя таблицы в статистический класс. Подскажите, как правильно сделать?

```java
public final class DBContentTypes{
 
 static String ctype_name;
 
 public DBContentTypes(String ctype_name){
  this.ctype_name = ctype_name;
 }
 
 public static class Employer implements BaseColumns {
 
public static final String TABLE_NAME = DBContentTypes.ctype_name;// Если так, то ошибка при заполнении таблицы данными. newRowId = -1
 
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "blog";// Так работает.
 
}
 
}
```

Comment: Инициализируйте значение в конструкторе